# Algolia Kotlin DSL query using AND + OR

Tags: kotlin, algolia

Example Search Data Structure:

```json
{
  "tpe": "HOME",
  "sid": "fyyb1-YQWMAs6Y8vGrk6OAcgjZ-XzTY03Ngfr",
  "sessionCreatedAtUtc": 1623854018195,
  "title": "Baked Enchiladas",
  "recipeCreatedAtUtc": 1623854008999,
  "releaseStatus": 0,
  "rid": "iBtk3PJ7HS9JKLRu4PHa",
  "uid": "SelHOKTaw1k4WZpTH9y",
  "desc": "Some info about this recipe...",
  "objectID": "iBtk3PJ7HS9JKLRu4PHa"
}
```

Query I am unable to build:

**Search for text, where uid = "SelHOKTaw1k4WZpTH9y" OR (tpe = "PRO" AND releaseStatus=1)**

So far I have only been able to get the latter part of filtering to work:

```kotlin
filters {
    and {
        facet("tpe", "PRO")
        facet("releaseStatus", 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the filtering settings in configuration under Algolia Dashborad?

Answer (score 0):

### For anyone else that struggled through this, I found a solution.

First and foremost, from the Algolia docs:

> Combining ANDs and ORs# While you may use as many ANDs and ORs as you
> need, you’ll need to be careful about how you combine them.
>
> For performance reasons, we do not allow you to put groups of ANDs
> within ORs. Here are some considerations to take into account:
>
> We allow ( x AND (y OR z) AND (a OR b) )
>
> We allow ( x AND y OR z AND a OR b )
>
> We **don’t** allow *( x OR ( y AND z) OR ( a AND b) )*
>
> We **don’t** allow *(a AND b) OR (c AND d)*

[Source](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/in-depth/combining-boolean-operators/)

So the query I was attempting to develop was not easily possible.

In the Kotlin Algolia SDK:

```kotlin
and {
    facet("tpe", "PRO")
    facet("releaseStatus", 1)
}
```

Means `tpe = PRO AND releaseStatus = 1`. You can verify this when you attach your debugger to the result from the `query.filter` DSL block.

```kotlin
filter {
   and {
      facet("tpe", "PRO")
      facet("releaseStatus", 1)
   } 
   orFacet {
      facet("uid", "SelHOKTaw1k4WZpTH9y")
      facet("rid", "iBtk3PJ7HS9JKLRu4PHa")
   }
}
```

Means `(tpe = PRO AND releaseStatus = 1) AND (uid = SelHOKTaw1k4WZpTH9y OR rid = iBtk3PJ7HS9JKLRu4PHa)`. The junction between all blocks in the filter block is always AND. And that aligns with the documentation.

My solution: Add another datapoint in search structure. I combined "tpe" and "releaseStatus" into a single attribute. `tpeRe = PRO-1`.

The resulting query that fits my original question:

```kotlin
filters {
    orFacet {
        facet("uid", userId)
        facet("tpeRs", "PRO-1")
    }
}
```